# Bootstrap element with 2 columns?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
```

The above bootstrap element has 2 columns(col-sm-6 & col-md-4) within its element. 
What does that mean?

Comment: You didn't actually include any code...also, if you want to learn Bootstrap, I suggest starting here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: For helping you it would be better to post part of the code you have doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each bootstrap element can have another `row` and columns in it. For example if your element is 100px wide and you have 4 and 6 columns then you get 40px and 60px, minus padding of course.

See `Two columns with two nested columns` on https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 0):

The `.col-md-` prefix takes effect on medium devices (≥992px)
The `.col-sm-` prefix takes effect on small devices (≥768px)

You can read more about this on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Using both classes at the same time will let you achieve different behavior depending on the the device/resolution of the user.

For example, with the same markup and no additional CSS, you may achieve three columns side by side on bigger resolutions and 2 columns side by side and one beneath them on smaller resolutions

[image]

You can view and play around with this example on codepen: http://codepen.io/rebagliatte/pen/GNKvOB

Answer (score 0):

- `col-xs-*`  ---> Extra small devices (phones, up to 480px)
- `col-sm-*`  ---> Small devices (tablets, 768px and up)
- `col-md-*`  ---> Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up)
- `col-lg-*`  ---> Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)

Each class above kicks in depending on the screen size.

So in your case col-sm-6 & col-md-4 .

Your container takes up 6 columns for small devices and 4 columns for medium devices and up.

Let's say if the screen size goes to extra small devices since we dont have anything specified by default it takes up full width available that being 12 columns.

Hope this helps :)